# Is there a way to make linux open a browser window at login?

Tags: raspbian, startup, browser

How can I make Linux open up Chromium when I log in (I use auto-login on Raspbian)?

My browser is already configured to open at an specific page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your use case you might want to use one of the following two approaches:

## Start in normal Desktop Environment

LXDE implements [freedesktop.org's autostart specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html). You can thus create a file `~/.config/autostart/chromium.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

Create the "autostart" directory if it doesn't exist, yet. This approach will also work with other desktop environments that implement the autostart specification.

## Start in Kiosk Mode

Create a file `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` with the following content:

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

This will start your browser in kiosk mode. Again you might need to create the directories and the file in case they don't exist.